# post request from android to node.js

Tags: android, node.js, android-volley

this is the class ([link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5757ef4cb0682ebfac4e)) I use to make a post request to nodejs. When I use pc's localhost url pointing to http://10.0.2.2:3000/postRoute , everything works ok, but when the url points to that same app located in internet (azure websites) I get `E/Volley: [122] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for myUrl`

Comment: you should share error in node console with us? is it possible?

Comment: Now I don't have access to azurewebsites. I will be able to do it later today. However, my made local machine's node.js app accesible via port fowarding on my router, I get response correctly, so this has to be something in azurewebsites